# How to us grep -F and -q command

Tags: bash, cron, grep

```
crontab -l | grep -q "*/5 * * * * echo hello"  && echo 'Already Exist' || echo 'entry does not exist' && (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * echo "hello"") | crontab -
```

What this will do is it's gonna check whether there is a cronjob in crontab or not, if there is it will create a new cronjob, but if there's already cronjob so it will echo 'Already Exist'.

The problem here is the `-q` option that cannot grep those cronjob strings. I need to use `-F` for the exact string but when I use it the output from grep will echo in the crontab (it will duplicate).

How to use `-F` without outputting the result of finding in the crontab?

Comment: Use: `grep -Fq`

Comment: I wouldn't use this complex mess of `&&`s and `||`s -- I don't think it does what you think it does, but it's hard to tell for sure and that's bad. Just use a proper `if ... then ... else ... fi` statement and avoid confusion.